# How to get next form content in python

Tags: python, forms, web

This is my first script(also post) in python.

In script i filled form content and submit it. So After submitting form it will generate result on next form. Now the issue is next form link not static, it will changed according data entered in previous form. See below some code of my script

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()

browser.open('https://example.com')

browser.select_form(nr=1)
browser.form["MyIDNO"] = '000D6F0004C46834'
browser.form["RuleID"] = '0109108301234567890A'
browser.submit()
```

Above code just fill data and submit it. Now i want next opened form content. I am getting dynamic link as below

https://example.com/index.php?option=com_gencert&task=results&tmpl=gencert&cfId=189537&MyIDNO=000D6F0004C46834&RuleID=0109108301234567890A&esKey=

As seen in above link, it will generated based on `MyIDNO` and `RuleID`.

I tried one solution as below

```
html = browser.response().read()
print html
```

It will print all content in html form. Now i need to parse specific data. See below some output

```
<tr>
<td><strong>User key: </strong></td>
<td>0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Institute id: </strong></td>
<td>
      030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267<br/>000d6f0004c468345445535453454341010910830123<br/>4567890a<br/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>part id:</strong></td>
<td>00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

From above content i need below output

```
User key: 0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8
Institute id: 030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267000d6f0004c4683454455354534543410109108301234567890a
part id: 00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6
```

Comment: You should also include what library you are using.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I am using `mechanize`.

Comment: What does `browser.submit()` return?

Comment: @Railslide how can i check it? I really new to python.

Comment: `a = browser.submit(); print a`

Comment: @Railslide It will return `<response_seek_wrapper at 0x235f300 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x2380300 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0237F3B0>>>`

Comment: Also i have tried different method to read data using `html = browser.response().read()`. Now i have all data of form in `html` form. But now i need to parse specific data from that see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the html document you can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for getting the data you need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# submit form as per your snippet

html = browser.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Process the content with BeautifulSoup.
```