# How to parse name and value from html files

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This question related to my another question [How to get next form content in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960536/how-to-get-next-form-content-in-python)

I have following some html content

```
<tr>
<td><strong>User key: </strong></td>
<td>0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Institute id: </strong></td>
<td>
      030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267<br/>000d6f0004c468345445535453454341010910830123<br/>4567890a<br/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>part id:</strong></td>
<td>00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I need to parse it and need following output

```
User key: 0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8
Institute id: 030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267000d6f0004c4683454455354534543410109108301234567890a
part id: 00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6
```

I already gone through http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and tried something but not getting idea what exactly i need to do for getting desire output. I am new to python programming. See my try

```
html_doc = """
<tr>
<td><strong>User key: </strong></td>
<td>0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Institute id: </strong></td>
<td>
      030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267<br/>000d6f0004c468345445535453454341010910830123<br/>4567890a<br/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>part id:</strong></td>
<td>00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')


for link in soup.find_all('strong'):
        print link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing, first find all the `tr` tags, and then for each `tr` tag, find all the `td` tags in it, and then print its text. Example -

```
>>> for i in soup.findAll('tr'):
...     for tdi in i.findAll('td'):
...             print tdi.text.strip(),
...     print
...
User key: 0200fde8a7f3d1084224962a4e7c54e69ac3f04da6b8
Institute id: 030780ffa3641183273ad548ae09872f9dcf4b0c4267000d6f0004c4683454455354534543410109108301234567890a
part id: 00ecd01536ff66296f9d572219d7acac02d59b24c6
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am getting output but still there ` ()` (space and bracket) at the end of each line.

Comment: Can you show your code , maybe it's part of actual html?

Comment: code is as posted in question. I just added your solution  .

Comment: Can you show exactly what is outputed? Maybe try the latest without the `()` in print